# How to edit grouped rows in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to edit all the rows in select rows displayed in edit but are also grouped in the following format:

NOTE: [] represents checkboxes and are either true or false in the database

---

A. Do you have any of this symptoms when you take following Drugs?

```
            Yes No   Sometimes   Not Sure  After 21 days   Indifferent
```

(i) Paracetamol []  []     []          []         []             [] ...

---

(ii) Quninne    []  []     []          []         []             [] ...

B. Do your eyes flicker when you use cold water with the following drugs?

```
            Yes No   Sometimes   Not Sure  After 21 days   Indifferent
```

(i) Vitamin C   []  []     []          []         []             [] ...

---

(ii) Quninne    []  []     []          []         []             [] ,,,

---

My POCO design goes like this:

```
public class QuestionCategory
{
  public int QuestionCategoryID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  ...
}

public class Question
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int QuestionCategoryID  {get; set;}
  ...
}
```

> In the View

**I am able to group the questions by QuestionCategoryID, now the problem is how to list out all the questions and edit it with the click of one button.**

---

So I have decided to make a wireframe of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Which one is the `QuestionCategory` and `Question`?

Comment: These are the tables (1 Primary table and the QuestionCategory is a Lookup table), I want to display all the questions in edit Mode but it has to be grouped by the category. Does this make sense or should I put up a sketch?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can relate your POCO to your example above. But with regards to editing, as long as you use a form and modify the values of your model then you can easily post it to an action in your controller.

Comment: Please check question, I have updated question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my solution below. I created 3 tables for Questions, subQuestions and Options. The options are tied to the parent question (assuming the options are the same for all questions).The questions and subquestions are displayed in textboxes (to make them editable).
You can modify it to suit what you need. Hope this helps.

This is my view:

```
 @model List<QuestionsTest.Models.QuestionModel>    
    <form method="post">
      <table class="table">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
              <b>  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Question, new { @class = "form- 
              control" })</b>
            </td>
          </tr>

          for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].SubQuestions.Count; j++)
          {
            <tr>
              <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].SubQuestions[j].Id, new { @class = 
                "form-control" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].SubQuestions[j].ParentQuestionId, new { 
                @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].SubQuestions[j].SubQuestion1, new { 
                @class = "form-control" })
              </td>
              <td>
                @for (int k = 0; k < Model[i].Options.Count; k++)
                {
                  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model[i].Options[k].QuestionOption, 
                  Model[i].Options[k].QuestionOption)@Model[i].Options[k].QuestionOption
                }

              </td>
            </tr>
          }

        }
      </table>
      <input class="btn-block btn-success" type="submit" value="Update" />
```

This is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Questions()
{
  var questions = _laraTestEntities.Questions.ToList();
  var questionModel = new List<QuestionModel>();

  questions.ForEach(q =>
  {

    var subQuestions = _laraTestEntities.SubQuestions.Where(s => s.ParentQuestionId == q.Id).ToList();
    var options = _laraTestEntities.Options.ToList();

    var model = new QuestionModel
    {
      Id = q.Id,
      Question = q.Question1,
      SubQuestions = subQuestions,
      Options = options
    };

    questionModel.Add(model);
  });
  return View(questionModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Questions(List<QuestionModel> Model)
{
  Model.ForEach(q =>
  {
    var questionDetail = _laraTestEntities.Questions.Find(q.Id);
    if (questionDetail != null)
    {
      questionDetail.Question1 = q.Question;
      q.SubQuestions.ForEach(s =>
      {
        var subQuestionDetail = _laraTestEntities.SubQuestions.Find(s.Id);
        if (subQuestionDetail != null)
        {
          subQuestionDetail.SubQuestion1 = s.SubQuestion1;
        }
      });

      _laraTestEntities.SaveChanges();

    }
  });

  return View(Model);
}
```

Model:

```
     public class QuestionModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public List<SubQuestion> SubQuestions { get; set; }

    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
  }

public class SubQuestion
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string SubQuestion1 { get; set; }

    public virtual QuestionCategory QuestionCategory { get; set; }
  }

 public class Option
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OptionTitle { get; set; }
  }
```